# AngularJs cross domain issue

Tags: angularjs, cross-domain, jsonp

When I try to use `$http.jsonp` to get data,the data can't show in the log,why?

```
userApp.controller('userCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',  'serverUrl', 'userService', 'loginService', function($scope, $http,serverUrl, userService, loginService) {
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.currentCount = 10;
    $scope.perPageOptions = [10, 15, 20, 30, 50];
    $scope.pages = [];

    $http.jsonp(serverUrl + "/admin/login/?adminName=root&password=123123&callback=JSON_CALLBACK").success(function(data) {
        console.log(data); //can't show in the log
    });

    $http.jsonp(serverUrl + "/admin/users?page=" + $scope.currentPage + "&count=" + $scope.currentCount + "&mobile=&userId=0&status=1&callback=JSON_CALLBACK").success(function(data) {
        console.log(data); //can't show in the log
        if (data.code == 0) {
            $scope.items = data.data.users;
            $scope.totalItems = data.data.numTotal;
            $scope.totalPage = Math.ceil(data.data.numTotal / $scope.currentCount);
            for (var i = 1; i < $scope.totalPage + 1; i++) {
                $scope.pages.push(i);
            }
        }
    });
}]);
```

Comment: does the api serve `jsonp`? easy enough to see by opening the url in browser. Not all api's serve jsonp

Comment: @charlietfl  I can get the data by opening the url in browser.

Comment: but is it jsonp? or is it just json? There is a big difference

Comment: @charlietfl. sorry,it is just json.How should I solve this problem?

Comment: if api isn't jsonp or CORS enabled have to use a proxy on your server or third party to get the data

Comment: @charlietfl.ok,thanks